Applying weights instead of matching
I want to conduct a Difference-in-Differences (DiD) design study. I have two groups (which you can see in the sector_eu_without variable) that I want to keep equal regarding certain variables: sex, age_group, education, income, ideology, and identity. Matching would be the ideal method, but I cannot afford to lose observations since I already have few. Instead, I thought of weighting respondents by these same variables. My idea is to examine the distribution of my whole sample and ensure that the distribution of these variables is "equal" in both groups.
Here is an overview of my data:
    ESTU PROV       date year_month sex age_group               sector_eu       sector_eu_without          sector_eu_fact
1  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     75-79 Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors
2  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     45-49 Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors
3  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     45-49 Export-oriented sectors Export-oriented sectors Export-oriented sectors
4  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     55-59 Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors
5  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     35-39 Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors
6  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     25-29    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
7  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1       80+    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
8  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     40-44    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
9  3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     60-64    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
10 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     65-69    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
11 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     35-39 Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors Import-oriented sectors
12 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     60-64    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
13 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     50-54    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
14 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   2     18-24    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
15 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     18-24    Non-tradable sectors                    <NA>    Non-tradable sectors
16 3202    8 2017-12-28    2017-12   1     18-24 Export-oriented sectors Export-oriented sectors Export-oriented sectors
   education indep ideology identity income     work_sit_fact class         media media_intns   PESO
1          1    NA        2        4      7           Retired     3 Spanish media           1 1.8325
2          2     1        1        4      8           Retired     3 Catalan media           1 1.8325
3          2    NA        5        3   <NA>        Unemployed     3 Spanish media           1 1.8325
4          1     0        5        3      5              <NA>     4 Spanish media           1 1.8325
5          5     1        3        5     10 Currently working     3 Catalan media           1 1.8325
6          4     0        5        3   <NA> Currently working     3 Spanish media           1 1.8325
7       <NA>     0        3        3      6           Retired     3 Spanish media           1 1.8325
8          5     1        2        4     10 Currently working     2 Spanish media           1 1.8325
9          1     0        4        3      5        Unemployed     3 Spanish media           2 1.8325
10         4     0        8        3      7           Retired     3 Spanish media           2 1.8325
11         5     1        1        5      7 Currently working     3 Catalan media           4 1.8325
12         5     1        4        4      8           Retired     3 Spanish media           4 1.8325
13         5     0        3        3      9 Currently working     3 Spanish media           1 1.8325
14         4     1        2        4      6 Currently working     3 Catalan media           2 1.8325
15         4     0        2        4      6 Currently working     3 Catalan media           1 1.8325
16         4     0        3        3      8              <NA>     3 Catalan media           1 1.8325

I would calculate the weights like this:
attach(DATA17_slct)
mytable <- table(sex)
prop.table(mytable)

mytable <- table(education)
prop.table(mytable)

mytable <- table(ideology)
prop.table(mytable)

mytable <- table(identity)
prop.table(mytable)

mytable <- table(income)
prop.table(mytable)

mytable <- table(age_group)
age_group_proportions <- prop.table(mytable)
age_group_proportions

detach(DATA17_slct)

Now, I have tried two different alternatives to apply the weights.

With the crunch package, however, for this purpose, I need an API key.
So, further elaboration of this point might be unnecessary here.

With the survey package:
I have in so far only conducted this for one variable (sex). Is there a way I could do this code for several variables at once? Because when I try to do so, I get the error message that the variables are not of the same length, and thus it seems to not be possible to do this process for multiple variables at once.


DATA17_slct_unweighted <- svydesign(ids = ~1, 
                               data = DATA17_slct, 
                               weights = NULL)
sex_dist <- tibble(sex = c("1", "2"), Freq = nrow(DATA17_slct)*c(0.4853061, 0.5146939))

dummy_sex_rake <- rake(design = DATA17_slct_unweighted,
                       sample.margins = list(~sex),
                       population.margins = list(sex_dist))

Also, when I have variables with at least one missing value in them, I get an error code (see below the example with my education variable). However, I do not want to exclude the observations with missing values from the variables. How can I circumvent this problem?
DATA17_slct_unweighted <- svydesign(ids = ~1, 
                               data = DATA17_slct, 
                               weights = NULL)
education_dist <- tibble(education = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), Freq = nrow(DATA17_slct)*c(0.1928934, 0.2284264, 0.1404399, 0.2229272, 0.2153130))

dummy_education_rake <- rake(design = DATA17_slct_unweighted,
                             sample.margins = list(~education),
                             population.margins = list(education_dist))


Error in na.fail.default(list(education = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, NA,  : 
  missing values in object

Now, returning to my principal question, when I want to conduct the analyses (OLS regressions), how would I implement the weights in a OLS regression? Because I do also have another weight Variable (called PESO) to assure the representativeness of my sample in regard to the population I want to study. In sum, I end up having two weight variables that I need to combine.
Again, my questions are:

Is the survey package and the coded provided above adequate for my problem? If so, how can I conduct this for several variables at a time?
How can I combine the two weight variables to include them in my OLS regression?


The point of applying weighting in a DiD design is to account for possible confounding factors that would be causal of the main exposure as well as the outcome. As for your data example, it's impossible to tell whether all assumptions are met. Is this exempted from ecological fallacy? Are factors like ideology and identity truly confounders or mediators due to socioeconomic status? Is one row a person? Or a country? Or something in-between? Also do you have more than just 16 rows? This is just a caveat emptor as you consider these methods.
The point of weighting here is to simulate a kind of better controlled study design. Unconditional weighting takes no account of the exposure or outcome, and just considers these variables (age, sex, ...) as a kind of stratification factor. The first roadblock you reveal is by calculating frequencies for this value not accounting for the main exposure. Calculating table(education) reveals nothing about possible imbalances between your comparator and referent groups. Rather the approach would be along the lines of:
w <- prop.table(table(age, eu_sector_without), margin=2).
For the referent group, set all weights to 1. For the comparator group, choose the ratio of the respective frequencies. That is if you had a 10% chance of sampling someone over 70 in the referent group but a 30% chance of sampling someone over 70 in the comparator group, you would downweight individuals over the comparator group by a factor of 0.33. Thus the comparator is indirectly standardized to the referent group.
Alas, this addresses the case of just one covariate/confounder/factor. Since you have more than one possible confounder (you have 6 in fact), this job requires multivariate methods. You could cross tabulate all 6 factors to obtain several thousand possible combinations of covariates and their associated frequencies or weights. However, it's likely - almost certain in fact - you would deal with the issue of weight singularity which assigns infinite weight to rare subject covariate combinations.
The Rubin approach of propensity weights jointly blocks the confounding effects of these factors through a modeling approahc. If the main exposure is sector_eu_without, then we appeal to Rubin's early work on counterfactual and simulating a design under which the randomization assumption would be met. That is, weighting is a kind of indirect standardization to balance covariates according to their predictiveness of the outcome. In this scenario, if an outlier is encountered in a reference group, the likelihood of upweighting a comparator according to likelihood of receipt of treatment is more certain. To obtain such weights, model the sector_eu_without as an outcome in a joint logistic model.
glm(I(sector_eu_without == 'Import-oriented sectors') ~ education + age + sex + ..., family=binomial)
The stored predictions (on probability scale) can be used in much the same way the weights from the earlier example with w to achieve a confounding adjustment.

the data I shared here is from one of my four data points. So, I would have to apply one of these two methods to the binded data? I have 952 observations (I only posted 16 rows to give an overview) Here you can find the full data. The rows are individuals, and the sector_eu_without variable indicates the sector in which the respondent works (either an import- or an export-oriented sector). Actually, both of my groups are treated (I have not a classical control group as usual in d-i-d Designs). The outcome is indep.

So, can I apply (one of) the two proposed methods to my (pseudo-)panel data just like that? As I understand it, both methods would give me the weights that I need to apply to my analysis (an OLS regression), but how would I apply them if I have another weight variable "PESO" which ensures the representativeness of the sample in regard to the population under study?
